# I need a C++ list with fast search

Tags: c++, list

I created a list with a key and description, however I want the key in the order I added to the list, not sorted by the key. Here's the application:

```
// The list I need of string pairs
// I thought about using map or set here but they sort the keys alphabetically. Unordered
// leaves the list in random order. I want the order to match the original adding order.
vector<pair<string, string>> stuff;

// A dictionary so I don't add the key twice
map<string, string> stuff_map;

static void add_entry(string key, string desc)
{
    if (stuff_map.find(key) != stuff_map.end())
        return;

    stuff_map.insert(pair<string, string>(key, desc));
    stuff.emplace_back(pair<string, string>(key, desc));
}

int main()
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < 1200; i++)
    {
        stringstream os;
        os << "option " << i;
        auto key = os.str();
        os.str(string());
        os << "desc " << i;
        auto desc = os.str();

        // Add twice to check map is working
        add_entry(key, desc);
        add_entry(key, desc);
    }

    // Display list in order added
    for (auto p : stuff)
    {
        cout << "key: " << p.first << " desc: " << p.second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question is example of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please describe the problem this code should solve. It this is competitive programing provide description of task. Then most probably it will turn out that your solution of actual problem has to hi time complexity.

Comment: What properties of  list do you need? O(1) inserts? Splices and splits? Iteration in insertion order?

Comment: I need a list with a hashed search to prevent duplicates. I want to preserve the order of the items added to the list. In C# I would use HashSet, what's the equivalent in C++? This is not a competetive programming exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't do *find* and then *insert*.

Insert already returns a pair which second element is a bool saying whether insert really occurred. Shorter and more effective:

```
void add_entry(string key, string desc)
{
    if (stuff_map.insert(pair<string, string>(key, desc)).second)
        stuff.emplace_back(pair<string, string>(key, desc));
}
```

"List with fast search" or "map preserving order" can be indeed achieved by combined map and list (consider list of iterators to map).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`boost::multi_index_container`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) to combine the properties that you desire.

```
using elem_t = std::pair<std::string, std::string>; // or struct elem_type { std::string key; std::string value };
using stuff_t = boost::multi_index_container<
    elem_t, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
        boost::multi_index::sequenced<>, // iterates in insertion order
        boost::multi_index::hashed_unique< // ensures unique keys
            boost::multi_index::member<elem_t, std::string, &elem_type::first>>>>;


int main()
{
    stuff_t entries;
    auto & index = entries.get<0>();

    for (auto i = 0; i < 1200; i++)
    {
        std::stringstream os;
        os << "option " << i;
        auto key = os.str();
        os.str(string());
        os << "desc " << i;
        auto desc = os.str();

        // Add twice to check map is working
        index.emplace_back(key, desc);
        index.emplace_back(key, desc);
    }

    for (auto p : index)
    {
        std::cout << "key: " << p.first << " desc: " << p.second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We're not using Boost.